# problem in running program after building in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have developed a small application and was working fine on developing machine but when i installed it on another computer and double click on it to start it starts and after splash screen it gives don't send error [ an error occured ] and getting closed ..... how can i fix that....is there any extension missing or there is any other problem...

Comment: You need to show us what the error was that it gave you. A little more detail might help us help you.

Comment: what exactly happens after splash screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a [Setup and Deployment project](http://aspalliance.com/622). You have to use to **Install and Run** the project.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing 3rd party assemblies. As Shoban suggested, create a setup project (ClickOnce perhaps) and make sure all the required 3rd party and yours assemblies are included.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to consider including a user friendly exception handler in your project. This will provide you with better information when something unexpected happens to your program.

See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exception/ExceptionHandling.aspx) written by [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) about exception handling.